# Vue Js : This dependency was not found: * core-js/fn/promise

Tags: vue.js, promise

I have an Vuejs App using promise but get this error :
`This dependency was not found: core-js/fn/promise in ./src/store/index.js To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/fn/promise`  
my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

I run the command npm install --save core-js/fn/promise ,but nothing change

Comment: did you try npm uninstall and then re npm-install ?

Comment: no i didn't I will try

Comment: don't work again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same err today, reason is `import { reject } from "core-js/fn/promise"`,
I delete it then app compiled successfully.

Comment: It works. In my case, VSCode automatically added the `import ...` line.

Answer (score 2):

Try update your `core-js` dependency version by:

```sh
npm install core-js
// or
yarn add core-js
```

---

The error is a result of `yourProject/node_modules/core-js` is not sync with your code.

You're importing `core-js/fn/promise`, but the build tool not found it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with **core-js** when I tried to start a **Vue** app, this was the error:

```
core-js/modules/es6.array.find in ./src/state/helpers.js,
* core-js/modules/es6.function.name in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/_base-link.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/_base-icon.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 4 others
...
..
..
```

my fix was to update dependencies and my **package.json** after the update is the next:

```
{
 ...
 "dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^2.6.12",
  "vue": "2.5.16"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
 }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Do the following steps:

```
npm install name dependency,
npm install
```

It's perfectly running for me.